# Image on every page, possible empty box and non square images? (two sided report)

Tags: graphics, double-sided, wrap, zwpagelayout, everypage

I've got an alternating backgroundimage (added with the background and iffoddpage package). These backgroundimages basically have a logo in the top left/right corner. The problem that arises is, that the text now covers the logo, since this is only in the background.

Therefore, is there a way to add a box in the top right/left side of the page layout, so that the text does not penetrate this?

Otherwise, another solution might be, to add the logo not in the background. Here, one would add this seperately, though I have no idea how to add an image for every (even/odd) page of a report without adding it to the header.

If the Image would be included in the header, the problem arises, that the text could not continue to the left/right side of the logo!
The last idea I would have would be a blank image at those positions on every (even/odd) page.

Additionally, the logo is not square! I've got it in .png format with the rest of the image transparent.

Ideally, the text would therefore float around the actual logo and not the square .png file. In the example below the square version would be the box on the left and the actual text enclosing the logo would be the triangle on the right.

The resulting latex document should roughly look like this:

[image]

This is concerning LaTeX.